# Open source agile backlog for managing user stories

Tags: linux, open-source, project-management, kanban

I'm looking for an open source tool that can manage my agile backlog's user stories.

Similar to this specific feature in JIRA or PivotalTracker.

Right now I dump everything into a spreadsheet - but I want a tool that lets me link my user stories to my scrum/kanban tool (using webhooks, IFTT, etc.), move them around to prioritize, etc.